# How to get grep to run command after found first response in line-buffer?

Tags: batch-file, grep, pipe

I have grep looking for the word playback which only appears once at command output from mplayer and it's running on line buffer because mplayer's command output is changing constantly. But on the first detection it gets I require it to run a echo command.

```
youtube-dl -q -f 95 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ -o- | mplayer -novideo -msglevel all=5 -cache 1024 - | grep --line-buffered playback && echo Done
```

This is what i'm currently attempting to use but it does not work due to what I assume is grep not thinking it's done looking.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but you're running this on Windows, right? The [batch-file] tag is exclusively meant for the Windows command line, but the programs you're using are typically *NIX-based.

Comment: Yes, I am. I thought it might sound funny but i'm using a Windows version of grep because nothing has a line-buffer that works natively in windows so I went with something easy and that I knew how to use.

Comment: I can get the music to play and `grep` finds the "Starting playback..." line, but `echo Done` will never happen until the stream ends because of how `&&` works. If you want it to echo Done when you kill the process, you can change it to `&` instead.

Comment: Change `&& echo Done` by `| ( set /P "=" & echo Done )`. The `set /P` command waits until it receive a line from grep, and then continue to the `echo`...

Comment: Could you send this as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `&& echo Done` by `| ( set /P "=" & echo Done )`, that is:

```
youtube-dl -q -f 95 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHW1oY26kxQ -o- | mplayer -novideo -msglevel all=5 -cache 1024 - | grep --line-buffered playback | ( set /P "=" & echo Done )
```

The `set /P` command waits until it receive a line from grep, and then continue to the `echo` command.